# Linq query containing null value

Tags: c#, linq

```
var records = from entity in q1.question_papers
              select new
              {
                  QuestionPaperID = entity.QUESTION_PAPER_ID,
                  SubjectID = entity.SUBJECT_ID,       
                  PreviousAttempts = SubIdAtt.Where(c => c.SUBID == entity.SUBJECT_ID)
                                             .Select(c => c.ATT)   
                                             .FirstOrDefault(),
              };
```

Above is my linq query where in `PreviousAttempts` field I get null value if doesn't satisfy where. So instead of containing null I want to change this 0 if it contains null and restore original value if it doesn't contain non null value.

How can I achieve this since I am not able to change `PreviousAttempts` through for each of record?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [null-coalescing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173224.aspx) operator here e.g.

```
PreviousAttempts = SubIdAtt.Where(c => c.SUBID == entity.SUBJECT_ID)
                           .Select(c => c.ATT)
                           .FirstOrDefault() ?? 0;
```

Or alternatively, if you want to keep it all LINQified use the [DefaultIfEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419.aspx) method e.g.

```
PreviousAttempts = SubIdAtt.Where(c => c.SUBID == entity.SUBJECT_ID)
                           .Select(c => c.ATT)
                           .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
                           .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use the coalescing operator. `??`

```
           var records = from entity in q1.question_papers
                           select new
                           {
                               QuestionPaperID = entity.QUESTION_PAPER_ID,
                               SubjectID = entity.SUBJECT_ID,

                               PreviousAttempts = SubIdAtt.Where(c => c.SUBID == entity.SUBJECT_ID).Select(c => c.ATT).FirstOrDefault() ?? 0
                           };
```